# Plot area strange behavior when changing date range

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm having an issue with Plot Area that is displaying weird after changing zoom(date range)

As you can see on the following screens:
[1M interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvoJw.png)

Then when I change to -3M:
[from 1M interval to 3M interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rMSV.png)

What's intresting if I would start from -3M it would display correctly like on the 3rd screen: [When I start from 3M interval its ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k3NH.png)

I'm pretty sure my data is correct, it's probably highchart issue/bug,

Comment: Hi @laxytt, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jzrot6py/

Comment: Hi! :) I'm not the best with mocking data in Jsfiddle, but I did my best: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qouyerkp/38/ When you play with the zoom in the bottom you can find the red area, it should display from the 'line' to my min. But it crashed weridly.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue by setting the data to two points:

```
{
      x: 1460937600000,
      y: 0.85
    },
    {
      x: 1514505600000,
      y: 0.85
    },
```

instead of:

```
{
      x: 1460937600000,
      y: 0.85
    },
    {
      x: 1514505600000,
      y: 0.85
    },
    {
      x: 1514505600000,
      y: 0.8
    },
    {
      x: 1460937600000,
      y: 0.8
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qouyerkp/40/
but unfortunately it's not working as expected in my local env. because it won't start from Ymin. I don't know why.
[issue in local env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/837IH.png)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by the data-grouping feature. You need to disable it for the area series:

```
  series: [...,
    {
      type: 'area',
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6jz1cpvs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.dataGrouping

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping